# InfoPath People Picker search not working

Tags: 2013, infopath

I have a Sharepoint Online (365) form library with a InfoPath form. The form has a People Picker control on it. Previously you could click its Browse button, the search window would pop-up, and you could put in a partial name and search. For example if you put in “James” it would return all the James’s in the organization.

But this feature seems to be broken now. Instead it returns “No results were found to match your search item. Please enter a new term or less specific term.”. If you type in a complete name of someone it will find it. But I’m sure that the partial search worked before.

Is anyone else seeing this? Perhaps a recent service update has broken this feature?

Answer (score 0):

It is still working. i think the problem is with the data connection, if you are trying to publish the form on sharepoint form library please check your connection with your site collection on which you are trying to publish your form.

I tried your same scenario without the connection and it was not showing me any results. but when i setup the proper connection i can see the search window pops out showing all the names related to partial name that i entered.

Comment: not sure what you mean. I'm not having any problem publishing the form or running it, other than the Browse feature.
How would I "check your connection with your site collection"?

Comment: PS: I'm using this form in the browser, not the InfoPath Filler client.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after moving a list to a new server. The people picker field was not working and I tried all the steps mentioned above.

Finally, I deleted the people picker field and then recreated it and tagged it to the appropriate field, targeted group of people, and voila, it worked again. Don't know why, but it worked, it really did.

Hope this helps someone.